# Laravel: Do I need memcached when S3 is served via CDN?

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3, digital-ocean

Laravel [writes for Amazon S3](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/filesystem#driver-prerequisites):

> An absolute must for performance is to use a cached adapter. You will need an additional package for this:
>
> CachedAdapter: league/flysystem-cached-adapter ~1.0

However, I'm using Digital Ocean S3 with their own CDN. Should I still use memchached? Like it's recommended [here](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/filesystem#caching)?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, of course you still need memcached, because CDN is something that S3 communicates to the users (browser), but memcached is something that S3 communicates with your application.